# Refactoring lots of if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, refactoring

So I have a project to make a random-name generator, and currently I have prefixes and suffixes being selected by: 
A) The amount of letters in the person's first name, and
B) The first and last letter of their name.

The code currently functions as expected, I'd just like to refine the code and hopefully remove the hundreds of lines that have thousands of if statements.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ranName 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input, firstName, lastName;
        String firstPre, firstSuff, lastPre, lastSuff, lSuffMean, lPreMean, fLastLet, fFirstLet, lLastLet, lFirstLet;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Lord Of The Rings Elf name Generator!");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("First Name: ");
        firstName = sc.nextLine();

        while (true)
        {   
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("You inserted " + firstName);
            System.out.println("Are you sure?");
            System.out.print("Y/N: ");
            input = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            {
                break;
            }    
            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            {
                System.out.print("First Name: ");
                firstName = sc.nextLine();
            }
            else
            { 
                System.out.println("Oh well, you tried. Here's another go at it."); 
            }
        }

        System.out.print("Last Name: ");
        lastName = sc.nextLine();

        while (true)
        {   
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("You inserted " + lastName);
            System.out.println("Are you sure?");
            System.out.print("Y/N: ");
            input = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
            if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            {
                break;
            }    
            else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            {
                System.out.print("Last Name: ");
                lastName = sc.nextLine();
            }
            else
            { 
                System.out.println("Oh well, you tried. Here's another go at it."); 
            }
        }
        System.out.print("Your Elf Name: ");

        firstPre = preGet(firstName);
        firstSuff = suffGet(firstName);


        lastPre = housePreGet(lastName);
        lastSuff = houseSuffGet(lastName);

        lPreMean = preMean(lastPre);
        lSuffMean = suffMean(lastSuff);

        fLastLet = String.valueOf(firstPre.charAt(firstPre.length()-1));
        fFirstLet = String.valueOf(firstSuff.charAt(0));

        lLastLet = String.valueOf(lastPre.charAt(lastPre.length()-1));
        lFirstLet = String.valueOf(lastSuff.charAt(0));

        if (fFirstLet.equals(fLastLet))
        {
            firstSuff = (firstSuff.substring(1));
        }

        if (lFirstLet.equals(lLastLet))
        {
            lastSuff = (lastSuff.substring(1));
        }

        System.out.println(firstPre + firstSuff + " " + lastPre + lastSuff);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("The House Name (lastname) Translates to: " + lPreMean + " " + lSuffMean);
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");
    }

public static String preGet(String fN)
{
    String[] namePre;
    String fNN, fL;
    fNN = fN.trim();
    int fnCount = fNN.length();
    fL = String.valueOf(fNN.charAt(0));
    namePre = new String[53];
    namePre[0] = "PlaceHolder";
    namePre[1] = "Ael";
    namePre[2] = "Aer";
    namePre[3] = "Bael";  
    namePre[4] = "Bes";
    namePre[5] = "Cael";
    namePre[6] = "Cor";
    namePre[7] = "Dae";
    namePre[8] = "Dre";
    namePre[9] = "Eil";
    namePre[10] = "Ev";
    namePre[11] = "Fir";
    namePre[12] = "Fis";
    namePre[13] = "Gael";
    namePre[14] = "Gil";
    namePre[15] = "Ha";
    namePre[16] = "Hu";
    namePre[17] = "Ia";
    namePre[18] = "Il";
    namePre[19] = "Ja";
    namePre[20] = "Jar";
    namePre[21] = "Kan";
    namePre[22] = "Kor";
    namePre[23] = "La";
    namePre[24] = "Lue";
    namePre[25] = "Mai";
    namePre[26] = "Mara";
    namePre[27] = "Na";
    namePre[28] = "Nim";
    namePre[29] = "Ol";
    namePre[30] = "Onn";
    namePre[31] = "Py";
    namePre[32] = "Pael";
    namePre[33] = "Qu";
    namePre[34] = "Qi";
    namePre[35] = "Rum";
    namePre[36] = "Rua";
    namePre[37] = "Sae";
    namePre[38] = "Sha";
    namePre[39] = "Tahl";
    namePre[40] = "Thro";
    namePre[41] = "Ul";
    namePre[42] = "Uon";
    namePre[43] = "Ver";
    namePre[44] = "Vil";
    namePre[45] = "Wuo";
    namePre[46] = "Waal";
    namePre[47] = "Xae";
    namePre[48] = "Xen";
    namePre[49] = "Ya";
    namePre[50] = "Yae"; 
    namePre[51] = "Za";
    namePre[52] = "Zy";

    if (fnCount % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            return namePre[1];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            return namePre[3];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        {
            return namePre[5];  
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        {
            return namePre[7];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
        {
            return namePre[9];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
        {
            return namePre[11];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
        {
            return namePre[13];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("H"))
        {
            return namePre[15];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("I"))
        {
            return namePre[17];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("J"))
        {
            return namePre[19];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("K"))
        {
            return namePre[21];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
        {
            return namePre[23];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
        {
            return namePre[25];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            return namePre[27];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("O"))
        {
            return namePre[29];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
        {
            return namePre[31];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        {
            return namePre[33];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            return namePre[35];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
        {
            return namePre[37];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
        {
            return namePre[39];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("U"))
        {
            return namePre[41];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("V"))
        {
            return namePre[43];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))
        {
            return namePre[45];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
        {
            return namePre[47];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            return namePre[49];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Z"))
        {
            return namePre[51];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            return namePre[2];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            return namePre[4];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        {
            return namePre[6];  
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        {
            return namePre[8];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
        {
            return namePre[10];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
        {
            return namePre[12];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
        {
            return namePre[14];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("H"))
        {
            return namePre[16];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("I"))
        {
            return namePre[18];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("J"))
        {
            return namePre[20];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("K"))
        {
            return namePre[22];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
        {
            return namePre[24];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
        {
            return namePre[26];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            return namePre[28];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("O"))
        {
            return namePre[30];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
        {
            return namePre[32];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        {
            return namePre[34];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            return namePre[36];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
        {
            return namePre[38];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
        {
            return namePre[40];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("U"))
        {
            return namePre[42];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("V"))
        {
            return namePre[44];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))
        {
            return namePre[46];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
        {
            return namePre[48];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            return namePre[50];
        }   
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Z"))
        {
            return namePre[52];
        }  
    }
    return ""; 
}
public static String suffGet(String fN)
{
    String[] nameSuff;
    String fNN, fL;
    fNN = fN.trim();
    int fnCount = fNN.length();
    fL = String.valueOf(fNN.charAt(fNN.length()-1));
    nameSuff = new String[53];
    nameSuff[0] = "placeholder";
    nameSuff[1] = "ae";
    nameSuff[2] = "aith";
    nameSuff[3] = "brar";  
    nameSuff[4] = "bael";
    nameSuff[5] = "cael";
    nameSuff[6] = "con";
    nameSuff[7] = "drimme";
    nameSuff[8] = "dul";
    nameSuff[9] = "emar";
    nameSuff[10] = "evar";
    nameSuff[11] = "fel";
    nameSuff[12] = "faen";
    nameSuff[13] = "gael";
    nameSuff[14] = "gin";
    nameSuff[15] = "hal";
    nameSuff[16] = "har";
    nameSuff[17] = "ii";
    nameSuff[18] = "im";
    nameSuff[19] = "jin";
    nameSuff[20] = "jaal";
    nameSuff[21] = "ki";
    nameSuff[22] = "kas";
    nameSuff[23] = "lian";
    nameSuff[24] = "lihn";
    nameSuff[25] = "mah";
    nameSuff[26] = "'mek";
    nameSuff[27] = "nes";
    nameSuff[28] = "'nil";
    nameSuff[29] = "onna";
    nameSuff[30] = "oth";
    nameSuff[31] = "pae";
    nameSuff[32] = "pek";
    nameSuff[33] = "'que";
    nameSuff[34] = "quis";
    nameSuff[35] = "ruil";
    nameSuff[36] = "reth";
    nameSuff[37] = "san";
    nameSuff[38] = "sel";
    nameSuff[39] = "thal";
    nameSuff[40] = "thus";
    nameSuff[41] = "ual";
    nameSuff[42] = "uath";
    nameSuff[43] = "vain";
    nameSuff[44] = "vin";
    nameSuff[45] = "wyn";
    nameSuff[46] = "waal";
    nameSuff[47] = "'xe";
    nameSuff[48] = "'xol";
    nameSuff[49] = "yth";
    nameSuff[50] = "yl"; 
    nameSuff[51] = "zair";
    nameSuff[52] = "zara";

    if (fnCount % 2 != 0)
    {
        if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            return nameSuff[1];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            return nameSuff[3];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        {
            return nameSuff[5];  
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        {
            return nameSuff[7];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
        {
            return nameSuff[9];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
        {
            return nameSuff[11];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
        {
            return nameSuff[13];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("H"))
        {
            return nameSuff[15];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("I"))
        {
            return nameSuff[17];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("J"))
        {
            return nameSuff[19];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("K"))
        {
            return nameSuff[21];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
        {
            return nameSuff[23];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
        {
            return nameSuff[25];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            return nameSuff[27];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("O"))
        {
            return nameSuff[29];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
        {
            return nameSuff[31];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        {
            return nameSuff[33];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            return nameSuff[35];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
        {
            return nameSuff[37];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
        {
            return nameSuff[39];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("U"))
        {
            return nameSuff[41];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("V"))
        {
            return nameSuff[43];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))
        {
            return nameSuff[45];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
        {
            return nameSuff[47];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            return nameSuff[49];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Z"))
        {
            return nameSuff[51];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("A"))
        {
            return nameSuff[2];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("B"))
        {
            return nameSuff[4];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("C"))
        {
            return nameSuff[6];  
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("D"))
        {
            return nameSuff[8];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("E"))
        {
            return nameSuff[10];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("F"))
        {
            return nameSuff[12];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
        {
            return nameSuff[14];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("H"))
        {
            return nameSuff[16];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("I"))
        {
            return nameSuff[18];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("J"))
        {
            return nameSuff[20];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("K"))
        {
            return nameSuff[22];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("L"))
        {
            return nameSuff[24];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
        {
            return nameSuff[26];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        {
            return nameSuff[28];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("O"))
        {
            return nameSuff[30];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("P"))
        {
            return nameSuff[32];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Q"))
        {
            return nameSuff[34];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("R"))
        {
            return nameSuff[36];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("S"))
        {
            return nameSuff[38];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
        {
            return nameSuff[40];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("U"))
        {
            return nameSuff[42];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("V"))
        {
            return nameSuff[44];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("W"))
        {
            return nameSuff[46];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
        {
            return nameSuff[48];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            return nameSuff[50];
        }
        else if (fL.equalsIgnoreCase("Z"))
        {
            return nameSuff[52];
        }  
        return "";
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I was really hoping your program would run, I was excited to see my LOTR elf name.

Comment: This might be better suited to the code review site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry, ug_,I had to remove a few lines to fit under the character limit. And I will definitely go check that out Austin.

Comment: You may want to look at ASCII table. You will notice that alphabet letters are assigned consecutive codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String fNN, fL;
fNN = fN.trim();
int fnCount = fNN.length();
fL = String.valueOf(fNN.charAt(fNN.length()-1));
```

can be replaced with

```
fN = fN.trim();
char fL = fN.charAt(fN.length()-1);
```

then you can use the ASCII code of the letter to determine what the array index should be

```
fN = fN.trim();
char fL = fN.charAt(fN.length()-1);

String[] suffixOdd = {"aith", "bael", "con", "dul", "evar", "faen", "gin", "har", "im", "jaal", "kas", "lihn", "'mek", "'nil", "oth", "pek", "quis", "reth", "sel", "thus", "uath", "vin", "waal", "'xol", "yl", "zara"};
String[] suffixEven = {"ae", "brar", "cael", "drimme", "emar", "fel", "gael", "hal", "ii", "jin", "ki", "lian", "mah", "nes", "onna", "pae", "'que", "ruil", "san", "thal", "ual", "vain", "wyn", "'xe", "yth", "zair"};

int suffixIndex = Character.toUpperCase(fL) - 'A';
if (fN.length() % 2 != 0)
{
    if(suffixIndex >= suffixOdd.length)
        return "";
    return suffixOdd[Character.toUpperCase(fL) - 'A'];
}
else
{
    if(suffixIndex >= suffixEven.length)
        return "";
    return suffixEven[Character.toUpperCase(fL) - 'A'];
}
```

In this case your suffix even and odd are both 26 long as they should be so I put the length checks in each of the respective code blocks.

*PS: I highly encourage you to type out more descriptive variable names `fN`, `fL`, `lastPre` ect... are bad names, I have no idea what they are. Future you will thank you.*

Comment: Thank you for this, it's very useful. And I do agree that I should fix my variable names. At the time I knew what they meant, but after taking this weekend away from coding, I can't remember for the life of me. I will probably be using this solution rather than the one at the top.

Comment: I've implemented this into my code to replace all of the sections-- In the ones where I'm NOT determining odd/even (Last Name Stuff) it works (so I've removed the if statement and just have it printing the appropriate output based on letters) The version that I've copied verbatim, however, isn't working as intended, returning a blank as opposed to the appropriate string from the arrays. Any suggestions?
**EDIT** From what I've discerned just by fiddling with the code and tweaking, it seems the length check is the problem for some reason.

Comment: @PaytenFriend whoops, i had my condition reversed. it should be `suffixIndex >= suffixEven.length`

Answer (score 1):

Use an implementation of [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Let the key be the letter of the alphabet and the value be what you're currently storing in your namePre array. This approach will also let you dispense with the array because your Map is acting as a means of both storage and retrieval.

Take your preGet method as an example. Rather than writing all those conditionals, you can achieve the same goal in a more compact fashion, something like so:

```
firstEvenPre = new HashMap<String, String>();

// some code to load up your prefixes

public static String preGet(String fN)
{
    String[] namePre;
    String fNN, fL;
    fNN = fN.trim();
    int fnCount = fNN.length();
    fL = String.valueOf(fNN.charAt(0));

    return (String)firstEvenPre.get(fL);
}
```

Use some discretion in trying the code, I didn't test it and I've been writing Ruby lately, so I might have some brain fog.

Comment: Something like this?
`public class ranNameTest
{
    private static Map<String, String> firstEvenPre = new HashMap<String, String>();
    static 
    {
        firstEvenPre.put("A", "Ael");
  //etc
    }`

Comment: @PaytenFriend Precisely! Now you can just retrieve the values using fL as the key. HashMap is an excellent choice.

Comment: Right, I know how to set up the HashMap, I'm just hitting a roadblock at actually _using_ it after I've implemented it. How would I go about using that? Would I just call the Map method in the main method with the fL value in brackets kinda thing?

Answer (score 0):

After looking back at the answer, everyone seems to be right, a switch statement would probably not be the best solution, because it would help that much.

However you could use a map, which is basically a data structure that takes key value pairs. You could reduce your two sets of if-statements and initial declaration to something like this:

```
public static String preGet(String fN)
{
    HashMap<String, String> namePre = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String fNN, fL;
    fNN = fN.trim();
    fL = String.valueOf(fNN.charAt(0));
    String[] names = {"Ael", "Aer", "Bael", "Bes", "Cael", "Cor", "Dae", "Dre", "Eil", "Ev", "Fir", "Fis", "Gael", "Gil", "Ha", "Hu", "Ia", "Il", "Ja", "Jar", "Kan", "Kor", "La", "Lue", "Mai", "Mara", "Na", "Nim", "Ol", "Onn", "Py", "Pael", "Qu", "Qi", "Rum", "Rua", "Sae", "Sha", "Tahl", "Thro", "Ul", "Uon", "Ver", "Vil", "Wuo", "Waal", "Xae", "Xen", "Ya", "Yae", "Za", "Zy"};

    for (int i=0; i <26; i++){
        namePre.put(String.valueof((char)((i+64))), names[i]);
    }
    if (namePre.count(fN)){
        return namePre.get(fN);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: He's still going to have lots and lots and lots of conditions.

Comment: true, but its a step towards making it more legible

Comment: Reducing 50 lines of code to 48 doesn't make the code *more legible*.

Answer (score 0):

The huge if - else can be expressed as

```
int translation = 2 * (fNN.toUpper().charAt(0) - 'A');

if (fnCount % 2 == 0) {
    return nameStuff[ 1 + translation ];
} else {
    return nameStuff[ 2 + translation ];
}
```

The math-side of my brain is a little oozy right now, so let me know if there's some mistake here. This should work, though.

Though this is a hacky and incomprehensible code (remember to comment the shit out of this one), I think it is fine when it reduces 50 lines of code into 5.

Comment: Jesus, is it that easy? For real? I guess that's using the ASCII values for the alphabet, yeah?

Comment: @PaytenFriend That's right. I referenced it from here: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: @PaytenFriend If you think this answers your question, then please mark the answer as the solution (the ok-sign next to the post)

Comment: He is doing a case insensitive comparison the right computation would be nameStuff[ 1 + 2 * ((int) fNN.toUpper().charAt(0) - 65) ];